# NoSQL Recommendation for a specific need

Tags: mysql, nosql, bigdata

- I'm using a MySql table with the following simple structure :

  ID_A : int 8

  ID_B : int 8

  Primary key : ID_A, ID_B
  Index : ID_B
- This MySQL table contain more than 500 million of rows, and the weight is 20Go.
- I need to be able to perform those kind of query :

  ```
  select *,count(*) as cpt from table group by ID_A order by cpt DESC

  select *,count(*) as cpt from table group by ID_B order by cpt DESC

  select * from table where ID_A in (1,2,3,4,5,5) 

  select * from table where ID_B in (1,2,3,4,5,5) 

  select *,count(*) as cpt from table where ID_B in (1,2,3,4,5) group by ID_A order by cpt DESC

  select *,count(*) as cpt from table where ID_A in (1,2,3,4,5) group by ID_B order by cpt DESC
  ```
- I tried innodb and MyIsam, but even with a big configuration server, mysql can't answer the Group By query. I even can't do it from a script side, because it would consumme to much memory.

All the data can't fit in RAM (20Go today, but 60Go in a near future).

Should we use NoSql database ? MongoDB ? Map reduce DB ?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used MongoDB for large data, but for more than 10,000 keys you can use the mongoDB map/reduce instead of default groupBy.

You can found here mongoDB documentation for this:

[mongoDB groupBy for larger grouping operation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group)

Hope this can help

Comment: Thanks. I will take a loop to this doc, but I was wondering if MongoDb is the best solution for this kind of simple data structure.

Answer (score 0):

> select *,count(*) as cpt from table group by ID_A order by cpt DESC

err, that will parse - but its very bad programming style, I'm not even sure what it will return.

I suspect that it won't be much faster on a NoSQL system unless you've got a lot of concurrency and can distribute the load across multiple servers (which you could equally do with MySQL). So you'd probably have to look at sharding / map-reduce to parallelize the requests (again implying multiple servers).

Leaving aside the strange SQL, why not just denormalise your data - add tables for ID_A and ID_B counts then put a trigger on the existing table to populate the data into the new tables.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
`err, that will parse - but its very bad programming style, I'm not even sure what it will return.`
What is the best way to get the number of rows with a group by ?

About the denormalisation, you mean use a MySql trigger on table update ?